# CORS error only POST with Docker + Nginx + Express

Tags: docker, express, nginx, cors

This is my nginx config

```
    server {
        listen                               80;
        listen                               [::]:80;
        listen                               443 ssl;
        listen                               [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name                          domain.com;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/test-name/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/test-name/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test-name/chain.pem;

        # security headers
        add_header X-Frame-Options           "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection          "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options    "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy           "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy   "default-src 'self' http: https: ws: wss: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
        add_header Permissions-Policy        "interest-cohort=()" always;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

        # . files
        location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
            deny all;
        }

        # restrict methods
        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST)$) {
            return '405';
        }

        # logging
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined buffer=512k flush=1m;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

        # reverse proxy
        location / {
            proxy_pass                         http://server:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host              $host;
            proxy_http_version                 1.1;

            # Proxy SSL
            proxy_ssl_server_name              on;

            # Proxy timeouts
            proxy_connect_timeout              60s;
            proxy_send_timeout                 60s;
            proxy_read_timeout                 60s;
        }

        # favicon.ico
        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
        }

        # robots.txt
        location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off;
        }

        # ACME-challenge
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }
    }
```

This is the docker file where i create a db a backend and nginx config for ssl

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    container_name: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ***
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ***
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27018:27017

  server:
    container_name: server
    build: .
    stop_signal: SIGTERM
    stop_grace_period: 200s
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
      MONGO: ***
      MONGO_DB: ***
      INDEXER: ***
      INDEXER_TESTNET: ***
    depends_on:
      mongo:
        condition: service_started
    volumes:
      - server_data_container:/usr/src/app
    links:
      - mongo

  nginx:
    image: jonasal/nginx-certbot:latest
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      CERTBOT_EMAIL: "email@email.com"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - nginx_secrets:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/user_conf.d
    depends_on:
      server:
        condition: service_started
    links:
      - server
    
volumes:
  server_data_container:
  mongodb_data_container:
  nginx_secrets:
```

This is the server part

```
const app = express();

app.use((_, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

  next();

  app.options('*', (_, res) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.send();
  });
});

app.use(express.json({ limit: "3mb" }));

// app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ name: pkg.name, version: pkg.version });
});

app.post("**********");
```

Get works correctly, POST dont work

I have tried changing nginx config and express using cors() module but dont work.

I think is something related to nginx config + docker.

There is some way to debug this config?

Comment: `app.post("**********");` what is `**********`?  You'll note the catch-all path for `options` is `*`.

Comment: I suspect if you want CORS to work you should also be allowing OPTIONS here  `($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST)$)`

Comment: app.post("***") is an example of an endpoint that works in postman but dont work in browser